# RegEx How to find text between two strings

Tags: regex

I have this text

```
XXX
text 
XXX

XXX
text 
XXX

XXX
text 
XXX
```

and i want to capture  the text between the XXX and XXX.
(i am trying to get chapters out from a book )

```
 /XXX.*XXX/
```

This will capture the first begin and the last end

```
 /XXX.*?XXX/
```

This will skip every second chapter

Thanks ahead
Barak

Comment: what regexp flavour/tool are you using?

Answer (score 4):

If you text contains line feeds (`\n`) you'll need to add the "dot matched newline" switch to your regex, as well as making your match "non greedy":

```
/(?s)XXX.*?XXX/
```

Edited: Thanks to Alan's comment - I had the wrong switch: `(?s)` is correct

Comment: Multiline mode alters the behavior of the anchors, `^` and `$`, so it would be useless here.  Perhaps you're thinking of "single-line" or "DOTALL" mode, which enables the `.` to match linefeeds.

Comment: To work with reg-exes, you must know reg-exes. To code, you just know how to code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution using `sed`

```
$ sed -n '/XXX/,/XXX/{n;p}' text
text 

text 

text
```

Answer (score 1):

If this `XXX` strings are always in separate lines, i would suggest simple iterating through lines and picking it 'by hand'. It should be faster than multi-line regexp.

**python :**

```
delim = "XXX"
inside = False
lines = []
idx = 0
for line in file:
    if line.strip() == delim:
        inside = not inside
        if inside: lines.append([])
        else: idx += 1
    elif inside:
        lines[idx].append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description doesn't really match your examples.  If `XXX` is supposed to represent a chapter heading, there would only be one at the *beginning* of each chapter.  To detect the end of a chapter, you would need to do a lookahead for the next chapter heading:

```
/XXX.*?(?=XXX)/s
```

That should work for all but the last chapter; to match that you can use `\z`, the end anchor:

```
/XXX.*?(?=XXX|\z)/s
```

It really would help if we knew which regex flavor you're using.  For example, in Ruby you would have to use `/m` instead of `/s` to allow `.` to match linefeeds.